# Cannot find module error for interfaces in Angular Universal build

Tags: angular-universal

My [Angular 7 portfolio-app with ngUniversal](https://github.com/batbrain9392/my-portfolio) is setup as per the [official cli documentation](https://angular.io/guide/universal). I have interfaces set up for incoming data and some common functions.

```
"scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "npm run serve:ssr",
    "build": "npm run build:ssr",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "compile:server": "webpack --config webpack.server.config.js --progress --colors",
    "serve:ssr": "node dist/server",
    "build:ssr": "npm run build:client-and-server-bundles && npm run compile:server",
    "build:client-and-server-bundles": "ng build --prod && ng run my-portfolio:server:production"
}
```

**Interface description and folder structure:**

[image: Interface description and folder structure]

**Component using the interface:**

[image: Component using the interface]

---

### Problem

The universal build fails while running ***ng run my-portfolio:server:production*** following with error as shown in the screenshot.

**Cause:** Interfaces and common functions which are not registered in any modules. They're simply imported in the components.

[image: Error while running ng run my-portfolio:server:production]

Full error:

> PS C:\Acclaris\Practice\AngularPractice\my-portfolio> npm run build
>
> my-portfolio@0.0.0 build
>   C:\Acclaris\Practice\AngularPractice\my-portfolio npm run build:ssr
>
> my-portfolio@0.0.0 build:ssr
>   C:\Acclaris\Practice\AngularPractice\my-portfolio npm run
>   build:client-and-server-bundles && npm run compile:server
>
> my-portfolio@0.0.0 build:client-and-server-bundles
>   C:\Acclaris\Practice\AngularPractice\my-portfolio ng build --prod &&
>   ng run my-portfolio:server:production
>
> Date: 2019-05-10T10:14:15.321Z Hash: 49ca0a31b14b3f2ef33f Time:
>   28138ms chunk {0} runtime.274b2b523ee7c9b8154c.js (runtime) 2.19 kB
>   [entry] [rendered] chunk {1} es2015-polyfills.c5dd28b362270c767b34.js
>   (es2015-polyfills) 56.4 kB [initial] [rendered] chunk {2}
>   main.c6958b8ee410ac47c079.js (main) 708 kB [initial] [rendered] chunk
>   {3} polyfills.8bbb231b43165d65d357.js (polyfills) 41 kB [initial]
>   [rendered] chunk {4} styles.3e7ad83f8f97d37ca687.css (styles) 61.6 kB
>   [initial] [rendered] chunk {5} 5.da6e7079542863691897.js () 1.92 kB 
>   [rendered] chunk {6} 6.89f434210c8e48ff257a.js () 718 bytes 
>   [rendered] chunk {7} 7.04704f420e92f76cb831.js () 5.2 kB  [rendered]
>
> Date: 2019-05-10T10:14:28.776Z Hash: a1b5d85a17ec5299c6a4 Time: 8780ms
>   chunk {main} main.js, main.js.map (main) 4.17 kB [entry] [rendered]
>
> ERROR in
>   src/app/shared/components/portfolio-builder/portfolio-builder.component.ts(2,27):
>   error TS2307: Cannot find module 'src/app/shared/interfaces'.
>   src/app/core/portfolio/portfolio.component.ts(2,27): error TS2307:
>   Cannot find module 'src/app/shared/interfaces'.
>   src/app/shared/components/portfolio-builder/body/body.component.ts(2,22):
>   error TS2307: Cannot find module 'src/app/shared/interfaces'.
>   src/app/shared/components/sections/education/education.component.ts(2,27):
>   error TS2307: Cannot find module 'src/app/shared/interfaces'.
>   src/app/shared/components/sections/education/education.component.ts(3,33):
>   error TS2307: Cannot find module
>   'src/app/shared/functions/function-library'.
>   src/app/shared/components/utilities/edulet/edulet.component.ts(2,27):
>   error TS2307: Cannot find module 'src/app/shared/interfaces'.
>   src/app/shared/components/portfolio-builder/footer/footer.component.ts(2,26):
>   error TS2307: Cannot find module 'src/app/shared/interfaces'.
>   src/app/shared/components/portfolio-builder/header/header.component.ts(2,24):
>   error TS2307: Cannot find module 'src/app/shared/interfaces'.
>   src/app/shared/components/sections/profile/profile.component.ts(2,25):
>   error TS2307: Cannot find module 'src/app/shared/interfaces'.
>   src/app/shared/components/portfolio-builder/sidebar/sidebar.component.ts(2,32):
>   error TS2307: Cannot find module 'src/app/shared/interfaces'.
>   src/app/shared/components/sections/sidebar-section/sidebar-section.component.ts(2,32):
>   error TS2307: Cannot find module 'src/app/shared/interfaces'.
>   src/app/shared/components/sections/work/work.component.ts(2,22): error
>   TS2307: Cannot find module 'src/app/shared/interfaces'.
>   src/app/shared/components/sections/work/work.component.ts(3,33): error
>   TS2307: Cannot find module
>   'src/app/shared/functions/function-library'.
>   src/app/shared/components/utilities/worklet/worklet.component.ts(2,22):
>   error TS2307: Cannot find module 'src/app/shared/interfaces'.
>
> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! errno 1 npm ERR! my-portfolio@0.0.0
>   build:client-and-server-bundles: `ng build --prod && ng run
>   my-portfolio:server:production` npm ERR! Exit status 1 npm ERR! npm
>   ERR! Failed at the my-portfolio@0.0.0 build:client-and-server-bundles
>   script. npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is
>   likely additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
>   C:\Users\debmallya.bhattachar\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2019-05-10T10_14_28_865Z-debug.log
>   npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! errno 1 npm ERR! my-portfolio@0.0.0
>   build:ssr: `npm run build:client-and-server-bundles && npm run
>   compile:server` npm ERR! Exit status 1 npm ERR! npm ERR! Failed at the
>   my-portfolio@0.0.0 build:ssr script. npm ERR! This is probably not a
>   problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
>   C:\Users\debmallya.bhattachar\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2019-05-10T10_14_28_983Z-debug.log
>   npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! errno 1 npm ERR! my-portfolio@0.0.0
>   build: `npm run build:ssr` npm ERR! Exit status 1 npm ERR! npm ERR!
>   Failed at the my-portfolio@0.0.0 build script. npm ERR! This is
>   probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging
>   output above.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
>   C:\Users\debmallya.bhattachar\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2019-05-10T10_14_29_044Z-debug.log

Comment: Can you show the content of the following files: tsconfig.ts, tsconfig.server.ts and tsconfig.app.ts ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change import path of Portfolio interface from the one starting with 'src/app/*' to the direct path. 
For example, for your PortfolioBuilderComponent import should look like this:

```
import { Portfolio } from '../../interfaces/portfolio'
```

Comment: Looks like it works in my case. But the questions is, why?

Comment: You must be using angular 9+